# What are the differences among Standard ethernet, fast ethernet,1G ethernet and 10G ethernet?

Tags: networking

I want to know the obvious main differences among these ethernet. I have already read many links,but i cannot understand easily. I want to know only the differences among ethernet types. I have less knowledge about networking .So, I want you all to explain me as a beginner standard. THANK.

Answer (score 2):

> Standard ethernet,

Too vague. This is about as helpful as 'standard fuel', which can (and will vary). Best *guess* is that you mean 10Mbit/sec Ethernet, e.f. via coax.

> fast ethernet,

Usually a 100Mbit/sec connection over RJ45.

> 1G ethernet

Usually a 100oMbit/sec connection over RJ45.

> Usually a 10000Mbit/sec connection over SPF+ (e.g. directly attached copper or often using fibre).

Heck,that was an answer with almost no useful details. Still, without a clearer question....

Comment: *"connection over RJ45"*  -- RJ45 is a connector, and "connection over <connector>" is rarely used.  The verb "over" should have a conductor (like your other statements) rather than a terminator for its object.  So "connecction over UTP" makes more sense.  The newer, faster versions of Ethernet use a point-to-point star topology that avoids collisions, and require switches rather than hubs.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally, Ethernet is used over 'thick' coaxial cable (Normally yellow in colour) called 10Base5 (the '10' denotes 10Mbps); Fast Ethernet uses the same frame formats and CSMA/CD technology as normal 10Mbps Ethernet. The difference is that the maximum delay for the signal across the segment is now 5.12 microseconds instead of 51.2 microseconds; Gigabit Ethernet is another term of Ethernet in computing network, for carrying on the traffic at the rate of 1000 Mbit per second, (media types:1000BaseLX, 1000BaseSX and 1000BaseCX); 10G Ethernet offers data speeds up to 10 billion bits per second, also known as 10GE, 10GbE or 10 GigE, a more advanced technology for 10G connections over [SFP+ optical transceivers](http://www.fs.com/c/sfp-plus-transceivers-56) or direct attach cables.